# Storing JDBC Oracle Wallet in project

Tags: java, ojdbc, oracle-wallet

I have been storing my wallet inside my project's resources folder, and am able to access it using the following string just fine inside eclipse

```java
final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_high?TNS_ADMIN="
    + (Database.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Wallet_DB")
        .getPath().replaceFirst("/",""));
```

However, when I compile it into a jar, and then run it from command line I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
char <:> at index 4:
file:C:/Users/Me/Documents/test.jar!/Wallet_DB\ojdbc.properties
```

I know I could fix this by just moving the wallet to be right next to my jar file, outside the project,  and accessing it with a relative file path, but is there anyway to fix this so I can keep the wallet inside the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC can only accept a path which is accessible by `new File(path)`. So here the path starts with "file:..." is invalid.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  JDBC is for talking to databases so I'm confused by your answer.

Comment: So, since JDBC can needs a valid file path, and I believe that files inside jars cannot be accessed through a file path, then I can't keep the wallet inside the jar?

Comment: @stdunbar I'm looking into jdbc jar through decompiler. Seems like the path after TNS_ADMIN=... is processed at oracle/net/resolver/TNSNamesNamingAdapter.loadFiles(). This method looks for tnsnames.ora from the given path using File(), this is where the exception occurs.

Comment: @criticalbird - good catch.  I forgot that Oracle owns Java but doesn't know Java.

Answer (score 0):

The TNS_ADMIN property is for capturing the absolute path of tnsnames.ora file. So, try to use the absolute path. Also, note the file separators for both windows and linux. Use the [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) for reference.